# restarting Sierra, Mamp mysql does not work

Tags: mysql, mamp

I had installed MAMP to use a local wordpress site.

After restart the computer, MAMP does not able to start the MySql Server.
It seems mysql  desappeared from computer.

So I repeated the Mamp installation, server start but after computer restart, problem repeats.

EDIT:
If I try to execute mysql from /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/./mysql

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Anyone  fighted with that ?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was removing all files (but not directories) in the mysql dir.

So quit MAMP and then in the terminal: rm /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/* (or wherever your MAMP is installed)

If this doesn't work go back and kill all processes: sudo killall -9 mysqld

Comment: Worked here for an existing MAMP install after upgrading to Sierra. Thanks!